# Check if picture in imageview was captured from camera or gallery

Tags: android, image, camera

I am able to capture an image from gallery or camera and put it in imageview with following code:

**1. Capture image from gallery or camera:**

```
private void captureImageInitialization() {

    final String[] items = new String[] { "Take from camera",
            "Select from gallery" };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, items);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setTitle("Select Image");
    builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) { // pick from
                                                                // camera
            if (item == 0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        "android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);

            } else {
                // pick from file
                /**
                 * To select an image from existing files, use
                 * Intent.createChooser to open image chooser. Android will
                 * automatically display a list of supported applications,
                 * such as image gallery or file manager.
                 */
                Intent intent = new Intent();

                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                        "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_FILE);
            }
        }
    });

    dialog = builder.create();
}
```

**2. Show in imageview:**

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
            return;

        switch (requestCode) {
        case PICK_FROM_CAMERA:

            mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();
            imagepath = getPath(mImageCaptureUri);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);

            mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            // Log.d("camera ---- > ", "" + data.getExtras().get("data"));
            new ProcessUploadAvatar2().execute();

            break;

        case PICK_FROM_FILE:
            /**
             * After selecting image from files, save the selected path
             */
            mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();
            imagepath = getPath(mImageCaptureUri);
            bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap2);

            break;

        }
    }
```

***Now my question is how to check if the image in the imageview has been taken by camera or gallery beyond the onActivityResult() method?*** I try to implement something like this:

```
public void NetAsync() {

        if (mImageView.getDrawable() != null) {

            if (mImageView = bitmap) {
                new NetCheck().execute();
            } else if (mImageView = bitmap2) {
                new ProcessUploadAvatar2().execute();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: If you just want to 'remember' if a bitmap was picked from camera or from file then just set a tag like `imageView.setTag()`. But look at your code: for both 'pickings' you have `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);` So they are both 'from file'. What does it matter? Please explain better your goal. `if (mImageView = bitmap)` That will not compile does it? And = is ==? Moreover 'from Gallery' ? You do not know the chooser the user used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily get this via single check of request-codes in onActivityResult()... I mean those request-codes which you've sent while calling camera/gallery intent..